# Dictionary values not getting reset?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to run a relatively simple code, and it gives the desirable output the first run, but on consecutive runs, the values get stacked. Please help, I'm a newbie to programming as a whole.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

As you can see from the screenshot, the 1,4,1,4,1,4 stacking occurs on consecutive runs. I've tried the resets in two different ways in In[53] and In[57]. But it doesn't work. The only reset that works is restarting the kernel. I've also tried foo.clear(). Didn't work.

Comment: Please copy/past your code and not a screenshot: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Please include relevant code and example as text - it makes it accessible for those who have trouble seeing, it makes it searchable and it makes it easy to copy and run the code in question

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Judging by the pic, the `foo_clear` part (`In [57]`) is not yet executed after `foo_assign` part (`In [59]`). Are you sure the `foo_clear` is executed?

Comment: Please also include the value of `tuples` so that you have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can reproduce and explain what your code is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce:

```
tuples = [
    [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4],
    [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1],
    [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5],
    [4, 6], [4, 3], [4, 6], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3],
    [4, 6], [4, 3], [4, 6], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3],
    [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3], [4, 3],
    [6, 5], [6, 5], [6, 5], [6, 5]
]

foo = {}

for vertex in range(1, 7):
    for pair in tuples:
        if vertex in foo.keys():
            if vertex == pair[0]:
                foo[vertex] += (pair)
        else:
            if vertex == pair[0]:
                foo[vertex] = pair

#for vertex in range(1, 7):
#    foo[vertex] = []

print(foo)
```

It generated the same with your `print(foo)` but without `5: []`. Which means if the commented 2 lines were executed first (assigning `1: []` ~ `6: []`), my result is the same with yours. **Your first code snippet cannot assign `[]` to `foo[5]`, because `vertex == pair[0]` contradicts `pair = []`.**

If I un-commnt them, it definitely resets dictionary values to `[]`.
So, your `In [57]` must have been executed first and then `In [59]` is executed later.

Comment: I got this issue rectified by a friend, and he had some said something on these lines, apparently its a notebook thing where the executables should be in separate blocks and in order for it to work. The solution was quite bizarre as far as I could remember. Thanks for the answer nonetheless!